# Create new menu with a module

Tags: 8, navigation

I want to create a new menu in Drupal 8 when I install my module. How can I achieve this?

I don't want to add a link to an existing menu, but create a new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either include the menu in your modules default configuration by adding a file to config/install folder of the module:

system.menu.menu-name.yml:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: menu-name
label: 'Menu label'
description: 'Menu description'
locked: false
```

You can also create the Menu entity, perhaps in the hook_install() hook.

```
use Drupal\system\Entity\Menu;

function MY_MODULE_install() {
  $menu = Menu::create([
    'id' => 'menu_id',
    'label' => 'Menu label',
  ])->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Menus are just entities in Drupal 8. Just create it with:

```
\Drupal\menu\Entity\Menu::create([
  'id' => 'my_menu',
  'label' => 'My Menu',
  'description' => 'This is my menu!',
]);
```

Use this in the [hook_install()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/8.2.x) so the menu is created in the installation process.